# In Cmake pass flto=jobserver to gcc

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake, g++

I'm building app with flto and I want to parallelise it on all cores that are used in make e.g if I run it with `make -j4` then on 4 cores

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(a)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -flto")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -flto=jobserver")
add_executable(a a.cpp b.cpp)
```

where `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are any reasonable cpps (and one of them has main)

Running with `make -j2` gives me:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/b.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable a
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
[100%] Built target a
```

So, only one core is used. Is it possible to pass information about jobserver to gcc here?

Comment: Would taking an alternative like [`ninja` build system](https://ninja-build.org/) be an option? That has really speed up [my project builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327526/how-to-speed-up-compile-time-of-my-cmake-enabled-c-project) and the nice thing about CMake is that you can easily switch to generate another build environment (to give it a try).

Comment: @Florian, I'll look into it, but make solution would be preferable

Comment: What version of cmake are you using?  Your minimum version of 2.8 is ancient.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only fix to this problem seems to be modifying the makefile(s) generated by `cmake`. You will have to add the `+` prefix to all recipe lines of the form

```
$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script path/to/link.txt ...
```

where the linker command in the file `path/to/link.txt` contains the `-flto=jobserver` option.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may try forcing LTO job count:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS_IPO ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS_IPO} -flto=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please comment on this bug to bump its priority: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17781
In the meantime, you have to use fixed -flto=x