# cmake dependencies scanning slow

Tags: windows, makefile, cmake

Using cmake 3.7.2 I recently switched a project from Unix Makefile to Cmake with Unix makefile generator.

All works as expected and the main problems we wanted to solve are solved (command line length in windows).

I discovered a great thing that is dependency checking as there is no more need to clean in normal situations and rebuild unneeded files.

**Now the dependency is very slow (about 70s) when the all build is only 20s. Is there a way to speed up the checking ? Or to find the bottleneck of this check ?**

Comment: That's one reason why I use [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) as a `make` replacement in my projects. Newer versions of `ninja` even use an internal database to significantly speed-up the dependency checking (it doen't have to open each dependency file individually, especially useful if your file I/O is slow). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327526/how-to-speed-up-compile-time-of-my-cmake-enabled-c-project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU make dependency check IS slow.
Ninja was designed to be much faster ans IS definitely faster.
The update to Ninja is very simple as only cmake generator (-G) has to be modified.