# Very long linking time with -g and without -DNDEBUG options

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker, g++

I'm building a third-party CMake-based C++ project.

Building the project in release mode only takes a couple of seconds. The linking stage takes less than a second (when `make` prints *Linking CXX executable myproject.exe*).

Building in debug mode takes more than a minute. Most of this time is spent linking the executable. This happens even during subsequent builds after minimal changes to the code.

The difference to the release mode seems to be the [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) option vs. the *[-O3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O3)* *[-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1)* options. Is this behavior expected? I've worked on similar sized projects before (~18k [LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code)), but I've never experienced such a big difference in compile time between debug and release modes.

This takes 50 seconds:

> C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  [-std=c++0x](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) [-Wpointer-arith](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wpointer-arith) [-Wcast-align](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wcast-align) [-fstrict-aliasing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict-aliasing) [-Wno-unused-local-typedefs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-unused-local-typedefs) -fvisibility- inlines-hidden [-march=native](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/LoongArch-Options.html#index--march) [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g)   [-Wl,--whole-archive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Wl) CMakeFiles\myproject.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive [-o](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) myproject.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\myproject.dir\linklibs.rsp

Comment: Debug information can be quite large. Also, I think that the `-NDEBUG` option you mention is actually `-DNDEBUG` which is the `-D` preprocessor option to define a macro.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, I updated my post. I still find it weird that the project takes over a minute to compile no matter if it's a clean build or a rebuild.

Comment: @Jawap Is it possible that omitting `NDEBUG` enables _lots of code_ in some generic header?

Comment: @Jawap Please post your compiler/linker versions.

Comment: Another suspicious thing is presence of `whole-archive` flag. Typically it is used as a workaround to prevent linker from throwing various global objects (used to to self-register stuff for example) away.

Comment: What's your binutils version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327526/how-to-speed-up-compile-time-of-my-cmake-enabled-c-project

Comment: Can't you enable incremental linking ? (-r)  It should speed up at least incremental build.

Comment: Some frameworks will behind the scene enable much more functions in Debug than in Release, Qt for example (Q_ASSERT being dropt in Release)

Comment: Can [`-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fvisibility-inlines-hidden) really be split over two lines like that (space in front of the backslash)?

Comment: What are the three `-Wl` options supposed to do?

Comment: There is a forward slash preceding "objects.a" (all the other are backslashes).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, link times for large projects can be quite slow, especially in debug mode. Things that usually help are

- splitting a project to shared libraries (that's done, e.g., by [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) developers)
- linking on [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) (or [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs))
- using the Gold linker instead of the default BFD linker (or maybe even LLD as it's getting more stable)

Comment: There's also `LLD`, the LLVM linker, which is probably the fastest linker around and should be quite mature: https://lld.llvm.org

Comment: @valiano Thanks, I didn't mention it because it's quite new (it took Gold several years to be able to link world).

Comment: LLD is actually pretty usable. For our project (600MB ELF with debug symbols), it is ~8x faster than BFD ld, and 3x faster than gold (creates the 600MB ELF in 3 seconds!).