# Do you need to make after CMake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

It's my first time building a library manually so I just want to verify something. Sometimes, I run Cmake as:

```
cmake -SOME_SWITCH=ON ..
```

And this runs fairly quickly. However, after that, I run:

```
sudo make
```

Which takes a really long time (30-40 Minutes).

So my question is, if I do after that CMake again with:

```
cmake -SOME_SWITCH=ON -SWITCH2=ON ..
```

Do I need to Make again? And if so, is there a way to not have to go through the entire make again (I.e. only compile the new entries?)

Thanks!

Comment: most likely, but depending on the change and how your project is organized it should be faster on subsequent compiles. As for your question on performance, try suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/q/37327526/7088038

Comment: especially noteworthy: use [ccache](https://github.com/ccache/ccache)

Comment: @avigil I know this is late, but I just want you to know that I love you. I didn't know about ccache, but it has essentially taken down the build time from 40 minutes to 2 minutes! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

CMake isn't a build system, it's a build system generator.  This is why (to answer your first question), you need to invoke `make` after running `cmake`; running `cmake` generates `Makefile`s with the appropriate dependencies, flags, blah blah blah, and running `make` actually uses them.

As to your second question, you shouldn't have to rebuild the entire project again unless something changed that affects the entire project (e.g., you changed cflags or modified a header that *everything* includes).  After you've run `cmake`, keep the build directory around and you should be able to just run `make` (it'll detect if a `CMakeLists.txt` file changed and `cmake` needs to be invoked again).