# Can there be an impact on build time when include/link libraries PUBLIC or PRIVATE?

Tags: build, cmake

As explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04), in modern cmake you should keep include/link targets private. Your `CMakeList.txt` should somewhat look like this:

```
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_include_directories(myexe PRIVATE ${mylib_include_dir})
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE mylib)
```

Can it make a difference, regarding build time, if I use `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC`?

Comment: Can there be an impact on build time when you pass *unused* include directories to compiler, or *unused* libraries to linker? Exactly this is a difference between *PRIVATE* and *PUBLIC* options for CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake part mainly reflects your C++ module architecture.

E.g. if you have two libraries and one (B) contains a public class that derives from a class in another one (A), then the header containing class B will include class A. And this will be reflected in a `PUBLIC` CMake dependency declaration between both.

Optimizing your code/architecture by reducing dependencies has a lot of positive effects incl. compilation time. For discussion on the effects see e.g.:

- [Effective C++ "35. Minimize compilation dependencies between files". Is it still valid today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321679/effective-c-35-minimize-compilation-dependencies-between-files-is-it-still)
- [What techniques can be used to speed up C++ compilation times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373142/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-speed-up-c-compilation-times)

One of the general topics I'm  referring to here is often titled "Reduce C++ Build Times by Reducing Header Dependencies".

**Reference**

- [How to speed up Compile Time of my CMake enabled C++ Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327526/how-to-speed-up-compile-time-of-my-cmake-enabled-c-project)
- [CMake target_link_libraries Interface Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037954/cmake-target-link-libraries-interface-dependencies)
- [[CMake] Difference between PRIVATE and PUBLIC with   target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html)